# Giving same variable 2 separate values

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Below is a summarisied version of my code. The first for loop increments by 10 and there is a foreach loop inside it. The search API underneath contains 10 results so by looping 10 times will display 100 results using the 3 echo statements - a hundred arrays each containing 3 elements. Now I want to give the first url a value of 99 and the last url a value of 0, so the urls can be displayed along with their score. Thats where I'm having difficulty in the last self-contained for loop, the rest provided for context.

```
for ($i=0;$i<100;i+=10)
    other stuff
    {
        $bing_array = array ( 
            $data['title'],
            $data['url'],
            $data['kwic']
        );


        echo $bing_array[0]; echo "<br \>";
        echo '<a href ='.$data['url'].'>'.$bing_array[1].'</a><br \>';
        echo $bing_array[2]; echo "<p>"; 
   }

}

for($n=0,$z=99;$n<100,$z=0;$n++,$z--);
{
   assign bing_array[$n][1] value of $z
}
```

Can anyone suggest alternative functions/ways of doing this or see anything small that I may be missing??  I'm having difficulty conceptualizing how to do this, I need to echo out the original value of the urls in `faroo_array[$n][1]`, the values being urls. But I want a different variable to hold the score/rank of the urls at `faroo_array[$n][1]`. i don't think array__merge will work as the `$z` counter is not an array.

If this makes sense any suggestions are appreciated and TIA.

Comment: can the array indexes represent the url ranking values?

Comment: having `); {` in the bottom loop is probably a bad thing to do. ;) Also format your code to spot such issues!

Comment: didn't even think of that, but I need to compare the urls of different engines, so if bing_array[$n][1]>blekko_array[$n][1] display bing array[$n][1]wouldn't work as it would compare their string values instead of their alternative "score". I know i could make the 1st element an array of array($data['url'], $score) with score being a counter but I've tried nesting these loops and it just seems to get very messy.

Yoshi I'll clean that up now.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a "do not repeat this for loop within other for loop " function?? As in for(loop 100 times){
for(loop 100 times)
{
//loops only a hundred times and not 10000
}

loops 100 times
)

Surely there is it would make everyones life so much easier.